# How to give a .exe file to my friend(s) without their antivirus going crazy

Tags: windows, security, download, anti-virus

So I want to give this app I developed to my friend. I've tried a lot of ways (Gmail, WhatsApp, etc.), but his Windows antivirus keeps deleting the file automatically. I know he could just disable the antivirus, but I'm going to eventually give to give this to a lot of people, and I don't want to have them disable their antiviruses.

NOTE: The file is a .exe file, obviously

EDIT: You know those installer files for apps, maybe I could make one of those

EDIT 2: Here's the idea for the app:
It's very simple, it connects to my device, and if I'm running the server.py file on my device, the server.py file accepts the connection and we can send messages to each other.
Here's the code:
client.py (the one I'm giving as .exe):

```python
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = '[REDACTED]'
port = 12345

print('Connecting to ', host, port)
s.connect((host, port))

while True:
    msg = input('CLIENT >> ')
    s.send(msg.encode())
    msg = str(s.recv(1024))
    print('SERVER >> ', str(msg))
```

server.py:

```python
import socket, colorama, os

os.system('cls')

s = socket.socket()
host = ''
port = 12345

print('Server started!')
print('Waiting for clients...')

s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
c, addr = s.accept()
print('Got connection from', addr)

while True:
    try:
        msg = c.recv(1024)
        print(addr, ' >> ', str(msg))
        msg = input('SERVER >> ')
        c.send(msg.encode())
    except:
        print(colorama.Fore.RED + 'Connection closed!' + colorama.Style.RESET_ALL)
        print('Waiting for clients...')

        s.listen(5)
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print('Got connection from', addr)
```

EDIT 3: How come installers which are .exe file (eg. VisualStudioCodeSetup.exe): Aren't flagged by anti-viruses?

Comment: Tell your friend to allow the file in his or her antivirus settings. It has to be done by the user. If anyone could make an exe that would never trigger antivirus software, then that would be a big security hole. Also, how do we know the person is your 'friend'?

Comment: Ask your friend to check why the antivirus thinks it's dangerous.

Comment: If the file is not malware (false positive by the scanner) and is not too large you can simply upload it to https://virustotal.com The antivirus manufacturer will get your file and can white-list it if it is really not malicious.

Comment: @Robert it said 6 engines detected the file was malware

Comment: Which viruses were detected? Are you sure that your own computer isn't infected and so also the created `.exe`?

Comment: Keep in mind that premium users of VirusTotal can download all uploaded files.

Comment: The easiest would be to give us the URL to the VirusTotal report.

Comment: Executables produced by packers such as Py2exe, Autoit, etc, are very often flagged by antivirus engines. It is not clear why the Python code has to be made into an exe - Make your friend install Python.

Comment: Rename the file so it has other extension, e.g. 'txt' and then zip it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey He complains that his laptop can't handle it (He's so stubborn)

Comment: @CrabbyFish - read my answer below.

Comment: @CrabbyFish - we can't help you fix your friend's computer, or your friend.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey how do popular apps get away with getting downloaded on your computer?

Comment: Instead of trying to find measures to circumvent virus protection you should contact the six engine providers, provide proof of your app being virus free so that many people can download your app without being scared.

Answer (score 0):

If the exe is produced by py2exe, it isn't really a 'compiled' executable. It is a 'packaged' file in which the original Python bytecode is added to a cut-down Python interpreter so that a user does not have to have Python installed. Another script packager is called Autoit, which does a similar thing. Packagers are often used by 'script kiddies' to produce malicious applications ('malware') and not often used by professional programmers. For these reasons, many antivirus systems flag them as suspicious. Often a packager will use a compression or 'packing' format such as UPX, and this in itself can trigger antivirus action. I myself have used them for home-use, and I can alter the settings of my antivirus protection to allow them. If they get quarantined, I can flag them as OK. If your friends are using (e.g.) school-issued laptops, or they have parental controls, they may not be able to alter their antivirus settings without the permisson or help of the 'system administrator' (school, parent, etc).